# Adding File Paths to a DataGridView Column (C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview, filepath, openfiledialog

I'm trying to add file paths to the first column of a DataGridView through the OpenFileDialog.

Each time someone clicks "add fonts" it gives them an OpenFileDialog so they can add additional fonts (multiple file selection enabled). When the person hits "OK" I need a list of all of the selected font's directories to appear under the "Selected Fonts" column. Later if they click "Add Fonts" again, more fonts will be added to the existing list (and will not overwrite). I'm new to programming and this is kind of difficult for me. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: What did you tried so far? And where get stacked?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this one out. When you select multiple files in the `OpenFileDialog.SafeFileNames` while having `ofd.Multiselect = true;`, the selected files appear as a string array in the OpenFileDialog. So I made it so that `foreach` string in the `OpenFileDialog.SafeFileNames`, add a row containing the `SafeFileName` to the `DataGridView`. I hope this helps someone. I wasn't able to find this anywhere on the web and in my new programming venture this is the most complex thing I have come up with mostly on my own.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ofd.Filter = "*.SFP, *.SFL|*.sfp; *.sfl";
                ofd.Multiselect = true;


            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string[] ofdSelectedFiles = ofd.SafeFileNames;
                foreach (string fontFileNames in ofdSelectedFiles)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fontFileNames);
                }

            }
        }
```